# Notation Question $R^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

I am reading David Fraleigh, A first course in Abstract Algebra, and they mention in one of the questions about

$<R^*,•>$

my questions is, what does $R^*$ denote?

> Edit: some context
>
> The question is to show $<U,•>$ is not isomorphic to either $<R,+>$ or $<R^*,•>$
>
> where they are all groups. I am not asking for how to do it, I'm just not sure what the notation means

Comment: just to be clear, the question is about isomorphisms, so I'm not asking anyone to do my hw or anything

Comment: could be dual space; could also be units of a ring $R$; more context would help

Comment: cf. [units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory))

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a ring then $R^*$ or $R^\times$ is its set (group) of units. $R^* = \{ x \in R : xy = 1 \text{ for some } y\}$. When it's written as $\langle R^*, \cdot \rangle$ it is reminding you that the group operation is the multiplication operator of $R$ not the addition operator. If one is being extra formal, we should also include $1$ in that list: $\langle R^*, 1, \cdot \rangle$.